# Django - Unique list from QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a filtered QuerySet which has a ManyToMany field 'Client'. I want to create a unique dict of all the Client objects in the query set so:

```
Projects Queryset:
- Project1.client = <Client: 1>
- Project2.client = <Client: 1>
- Project3.client = <Client: 2>
- Project4.client = <Client: 2>
- Project5.client = <Client: 3>

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to end up with a dict of client objects:

```
{<Client: 1>,<Client: 2>,<Client: 3>}
```

Some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "a filtered QuerySet which has a ManyToMany field 'Client'." Query sets don't have fields. Is your query set a query set of Client objects or Project objects? The Project model you are showing has a many to one relationship to Clients.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
Project.objects.values('client').distinct()
```

[Link to Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) on queryset distinct() method

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I use inheritence, can that be the reason? What should I do?

Comment: You should open a question describing exactly what you're doing and what error you're getting.