# Retrieving unique values from queryset in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a fairly straightforward issue.

I have three models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The user can filter books and selects a filter for "Publisher-A" .Now I want to update the displayed filters for authors - not showing all authors  - but only the ones that that published a book with the selected publisher. So I need to retrieve a list of unique authors from the queryset, I suppose.

[I found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728283/django-unique-list-from-queryset) - but it seems a like a hack to me. Isn't there a standard solution for this? The problem seems so straightforward.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a list of `Author`s for a given `Publisher` with:

```
Author.objects.filter(book__publisher=my_publisher).distinct()
```

Where *`my_publisher`* is the publisher. The `.distinct()` will guarantee that an `Author` appears at most once in the queryset. This is necessary if an `Author` has written multiple books for *`my_publisher`*. If you would omit `.distinct()` it will appear several times: exactly the number of times that `Author` wrote a book for that publisher.